# Convert from Arrays.asList to Array

Tags: java, java-8, mongodb-query, java-stream, bson

I have this code as below :

```
fieldsToFilter.stream()
    .map(e -> Arrays.asList(
        Filters.ne(e, ""),
        Filters.exists(e, true)
     ))
     .toArray(Bson[]::new))
```

while executing I get `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`

`Filters.exists` and `Filters.ne` return new **Bson** instances. See the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/builders/filters/).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not just `new Bson[]{Filters.ne(e, ""), Filters.exists(e, true)}`?

Comment: What exactly is the expected result, please?

Comment: @OleV.V. seems to be of type`Bson[]`

Comment: Yes, @nullpointer, but how long and with what contents?

Comment: @OleV.V. it seems the OP want to create a filter for mongodb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` instead of `map` and

`Stream.of` instead of `Arrays.asList`

```
Bson[] result = fieldsToFilter.stream()
                   .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(Filters.ne(e, "") , Filters.exists(e, true)))
                   .toArray(Bson[]::new);
```

Comment: `Stream.of()` must be used, as the `Arrays.stream()` methods doesn't accept varargs

Comment: Correct @Lino, sorry I'm using my phone :( I change it

Comment: `Arrays.asList(..., ...).stream()` would have worked as well if that were the case. @Lino

Comment: @nullpointer that would just eliminate the creation of the `List` in the first place